# Reading an XML using SAXParser

Tags: java, sax

I want to read such a file:

```
<level1 a="1" b="2" c="3">
  <level2 a2="1" b2="2" c2="3">
    <level3 a3="1" b3="2" c3="3">
       <level4 a4="1" b4="2" c4="3">
    </level3>
  </level2>
  <level2a a2a="1" b2a="2" c2a="3">
    <level3a>
      <level3 id="0"/>
      <level3 id="2"/>
      <level3 id="7"/>
      <level3 id="11"/>
    </level3a>
  </level2a>
</level1>
```

**Note:** `level3` is actually used twice in different contexts

I have some pseudocode mixed up where I wish to use `SAXParser` in Java:

```
create new parser
loop to get tags
if tag is level 1
get its properties(a b and c)
save the values of them into level1_a,level1_b,level1_c
if tag is level 2
...
if ..
...
end loop
done
```

But i have never used it and I'm not clear onto how it works, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SAX parsing, you will need to handle a context on your side. You issue here is to differentiate `level3` node when it is below `level2` or below `level3a`. The best way is to handle a stack while decoding, of what is the current node you are in:

- push node (name?) on the stack after a startElement
- pop top node (name?) after the endElement.

In your pseudo code, your "loop to get tags" is actually a SAX callback that you register to the SAXParser. Each time you start it you can also push the node name into a Stack. Then when reading a `level3` node, you simply have to read the name of the top stack node to know if you need to read `id` or the triplet `a3` `b3` `c3` attributes in current node.

Comment: great idea, trying to implement